# Working with Dask, Xarray, Holoviews, Bokeh Datasets

Tags: bokeh, dask, python-xarray, holoviews, datashader

Currently have very large xarray dataset with 7 data variables, each with shape of about 60-80k (x,y) values as well as 4 years (give or take) of time data. Im working on creating a UI that will display 3 maps, 1 main map and 2 maps shown below of a selected AOI, as well as a scatter plot, a time-series curve and a scatter matrix. I wan't this all to be fully interactive meaning updating all plots simultaneously with dropdowns selecting data variables and time-sliders etc.The issue i'm currently having is with memory and render time.

I'm wondering if anyone has done anything similar to this and what the best way to go about doing something like this while being efficient with memory etc.

Comment: Philipp Rudiger has recently found some cases when interactive pipelines would create temporary values that Python did not garbage collect very quickly (due to internal circular references), which was causing some memory issues that have now been eliminated on the master branch of HoloViews.  So you may be able to improve things by using the next dev or real release of HoloViews. I'm not sure when that will appear, though.

Answer (score 0):

[xrviz](https://xrviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does interactive 2d visualisation and extraction for xarray data (based on panel/holoviz). Please try it out and help us to improve it - it is still a work in progress.